# Why setWidth does not work?

Tags: android, android-layout

For example, for a TextView in Android you have to set the LayoutParams instead of the setWidth method.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(100, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But why? In the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setWidth(int)) it says it would deliver the same result.

Comment: Interested in knowing as well. LayoutParams is a thorn in my side every time I have to use it.

Comment: Have you tried it manually in the xml, just to make sure a parent isn't affecting it?  or the other thing would be try .invalidate().

Comment: `setWidth()` works but it may be overridden by the layout params. So post an example of `TextView` `setWidth()` that doesn't work and the layout the `TextView` is in.

Comment: As others mentioned before me, the problem might be with the parent affecting the child view. Also, to which class does the `LayoutParams` belong, that you use in your example (`LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`, `AbsoluteLayout`, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use layoutParams because setting a different width or height can change all the positioning of the layout. All the view hierarchy has to accommodate to the new dimensions, the only way is changing the layout params. The parent then gets notificated and starts all the process of measuring the views of the children.